# Sync Gateway creates one document per change when used with Couchbase-lite

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

From what I have observed:

1. For every document you create, a revision-manager document is also created. This revision-manager keeps track of the latest revision and also maintains a history of all revisions in an array.
2. Every time you update a document, a new document is created (whyyyyy???). The revision-manager document's latest pointer points to this new document and adds the previous document to its revision history list.
3. So, in every update operation Sync-Gateway is adding a new document and also modifying revision-manager document.

This is very inefficient way of doing version control where a copy of the whole document is maintained for version control instead of just the diff as this is going to take a lot of space. (For example : It is taking 8.03MB of disk space for doing 500 taps on a single todo item in the "GrocerySync-Android" sample app. Also, the revision manager document has become greater than 2.5 kb and I am getting a message saying you cannot modify a document more than 2.5 kb in size. Why????)

Questions:

1. What is the _sync:local: document about?
2. Is it possible to turn off this default behaviour of creating a new document on update and keeping just the latest copy. (One way could be to delete older revs in the client but I guess this would not modify the revision-manager document.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a distributed system, especially used for iOS/Android and other embedded devices it's important to keep the full set of properties in each revision.

Using the patch/diff approach in such system could lead to more inconsistencies, for example an update would only make sense if there were some previous state too. Otherwise, showing the diffs of a document to the user wouldn't provide a great user experience. It's very well suited for other use cases however, versioning of source code for example (Git, Mercurial...)

It could be possible to leverage the patch/diff approach in the replication protocol. There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/issues/168) in the Couchbase Lite iOS repository discussing the possibilities of only transferring deltas of revisions.

If you only want to keep a small number revisions, change the `maxRevTreeDepth` property to specify the number of revisions to keep in the tree history of a document (the default is 20, read more [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/database/index.html#database-housekeeping)).